# How do you integrate order of operations for operators into a Programming Language's Parser

Tags: programming-languages, formal-languages

I'm writing an Interpreter with its own custom parser and atomizer, and I want to add an order of operations for operators into the language, both because it is nice for math, and also because it's necessary for truthy operators evaluating expressions with non-truthy operators correctly.

Anyone know an answer or any good resources I could look at?

Comment: The grammar needs to reflect operator precedence.  E.g. (considering just 3 operators)  expression ::= term | expression+term; term ::= factor | term*factor; factor ::= primary | factor^primary;

Comment: The standard reference is [Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) (i.e., the Dragon Book).